# Vim: Setting filetype in file works, but doesn't work in .vimrc - How to debug?

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing filetype based on file extention in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767024/changing-filetype-based-on-file-extention-in-vim)

I made a small syntax file for .erb files, I'm trying to get it to load for .erb files...

When I open up the file itself, it loads some other syntax file. If I type `set filetype=erb` then it uses the right syntax.

How do I check what filetype a current file is? When I type `:filetype` it just says `filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON`

I have a line in my .vimrc file:

`au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.erb set filetype=erb`

I think that should be setting the filetype, but it's not... Any idea how to debug this?

Comment: Type `set filetype` to display the current filetype. The default filetype for `.erb` files is `eruby`.  
You should also check `set syntax` to check the current syntax.

Comment: Thanks! it magically started working properly when I fire up vim this time. Both `set filetype` and `set syntax` shows `erb`

Comment: Well, in that case you should really thank luck, but I'm always willing to take credit I don't deserve, so you welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't use this but if you check the *filetype* section of *vim help* (type "*:help filetype*" from inside vim) it'll point you to what you need to do.

You should specifically check the new-filetype section (since you mentioned that you made a new syntax file for your *.erb files).

It describes four ways to insert a new filetype. Not sure if this is an overkill for what you need to do, but I hope it helps!