# Changing filetype based on file extention in vim

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I want to change the filetype based on file extension in `vim`.

I have the following code in the my `.vimrc`

```
autocmd BufNew,BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt,*.text,*.md,*.markdown setlocal ft=markdown
```

But when I open a file with the extention `.md` file, the filetype is not changed. I run `:set ft` command and it shows the output as `filetype=modula2`.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Edit:

I started to debug by renaming my old `.vimrc` file and created a new one with just this line. It was working properly. Then I replaced my old `.vimrc` file and everything seems to be working fine. Guess it was because of some issues in some addon which I am using.

But accepting ZyX's answer, since it thought me an alternate way to do this.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Are you sure there's not a conflicting line in your vimrc, or a plugin?

Comment: I am mostly sure that there is no conflicting lines in my vimrc. But is there a definite way to find out if there is a conflict?

Comment: The simplest way would be to use a new vimrc in which this is the only line (backing up your existing vimrc, of course). Then see if you can reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: It is most likely because of my first assumption: in new vimrc with just that line there is no `filetype … on` command. If it were addon issues then replacing just vimrc should not work (unless you are using VAM or Vundle which both have list of used plugins typically defined in the vimrc).

Comment: It is definitely not the first option, because I have explicitly set filetype on. I use Vundle for addon management. I would debug it more when I get some free time. But it is working fine for now though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wondering whether this line goes before or after `filetype … on`. In the former case you should try putting it (your autocommand) after this line. Better if you put it into `~/.vim/ftdetect/markdown.vim` and use `setfiletype markdown` instead of `setlocal ft=markdown`:

```
augroup filetypedetect
    autocmd BufNew,BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt,*.text,*.md,*.markdown :setfiletype markdown
augroup END
```

: it is the default way of doing such things. `~/.vim` must go before `/usr/share/vim/*` paths in `'runtimepath'` option in this case (it does by default).

Answer (score 14):

I created a `~/vim/ftdetect/markdown.vim` file with this line

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.md,*.mkdn,*.markdown :set filetype=markdown
```

Reading the docs for filetype, `setfiletype` only sets if filetype is unset.  So you need to use `set` for an unconditional change to a filetype.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get syntax highlighting for alternate file extensions by creating renamed copies of the target syntax file in the Vim\vim74\syntax directory.

To make *.md open as a .markdown:

copy markdown.vim md.vim

or paste a copy of markdown.vim to the syntax folder, then rename the copy md.vim.

(Running vim74 on win7)